# React problems with utf-8

Tags: reactjs, encoding, utf-8

I am working in a react solution using Visual Studio. My react .js files are encoded as UTF-8.

I am using some danish text and what puzzles me is that I have to rewrite ø to &oslash;

The reason it puzzles me is because the browser shows the UTF-8 replacement character so I am thinking it must be UTF-8 all the way through.

Am I missing something obvious?

Code just to show problem is in a render:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            Søgning.
            S&oslash;gning.
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Check the encoding of your files. Make sure your files are UTF-8, and in the upload procedure there is no conversion of format (so if you use git for deployment, ensure that git know your files are UTF-8 and not Latin-1, or that no conversion is done).

Comment: I am testing encoding with Notepad++, that is the best tool I know. It says utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to post the solution in case anyone else reach this page.

The solution was to change the encoding of the page. Just open page E.g. in Notepad++ and change the encoding to UTF-8 with BOM.

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like below for the representation of them in the js file,

```
import utf8 from "utf8";

const encoded = utf8.encode(Søgning)
```

If you are using this on the .jsx file, you don't need encoding for special characters like this. In the .jsx file you can use it like,

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            Søgning.
            Søgning.
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: There must be something wierd, that gave me Sï¿½gning. Anyways, I'll just use your approach with html encoding instead. Thanks

Comment: In your deployment scripts, it seems there is a conversion, and the tools assume you have latin1 (or cp1252) as source (and not already a UTF-8).